# Is there a Filo implementation of a BufferBlock?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I am shoving messages into a `BufferBlock`, which I then want to route into one of two BufferBlocks. The primary Block (P) will get all messages until there are a certain number of messages in the Buffer. Once the P buffer is filled I want to shove messages into a FILO `BufferBlock`(S). I then want to consume from these buffers via an `ActionBlock` where the priority is on S if it has messages.

I think I can figure out how to rig everything together just fine but I tried looking at the implementation of `BufferBlock` in corefx and I don't think I have what it takes to make it FILO.

TLDR: Is there already an implementation of `BufferBlock` that's FILO or is there a simple (relative) way to make the `BufferBlock` FILO by modifying its source from corefx?

Comment: Seems like the best fit would be a [ConcurrentStack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267331(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Yea I was thinking about that, I just wanted to use TPL stuff for cleanliness

Comment: Ended up using a Concurrent stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there already an implementation of `BufferBlock` that's FILO or is there a simple(relative) way to make the `BufferBlock` FILO by modifying its source from `corefx`?

Not in standard library. If you want to create a new block, you should implement the base interfaces (e.g. [`IPropagatorBlock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-dataflow-block-type#deriving-from-ipropagatorblock-to-define-the-sliding-window-dataflow-block)) or use static method [`DataflowBlock.Encapsulate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-dataflow-block-type#defining-the-sliding-window-dataflow-block), not to modify the standard block' code.

You can find additional information on MSDN or in official [Introduction to TPL Dataflow](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14782).

Comment: Just spent a few hours trying to do this, its to much for me to waste any more time on this at work. I'm going to leave this open in case anyone comes up with anything for a few days.